# Help with terminology and/or method: find parameters that minimize cost function for each cluster of initial conditions?

Tags: terminology, dimensionality-reduction

This is a bit embarrassing but I can't even find the words to properly do a Google search.

I am doing simulations and I am trying to develop a better adaptation process. The process has seven adjustable parameters, most continuous, a few are discrete (integers). At the end of each simulation, I can draw one to three different "performance" measures. Additionally, I can feed different initial conditions to a simulation, with the same adaptation parameters, and obtain different values for the performance measures.

If I call $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$ the maybe-not-independent, adjustable parameters that relate to the adaptation process, $e_1, e_2, e_3$ the performance measures, and $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_m$ the set of initial conditions, a combination values of $\{s_k,p_j\}$ for $k=1,2,\dots,m$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$ will give me one value for each of the $e_l$. I am trying to identify if there is either a best set of values for $\{p_j\}$ for all $\{s_k\}$ or, maybe, a clustered version of this.

After performing simulations for a large number of initial conditions, for each of a wide range of adaptation parameters, I have a data set with $n+m+3$ columns that I don't know how to visualize or analyze.

My questions would be:

- What terminology should I be using for the $p_j$, $s_k$ (which I pick) and $e_l$ (which I measure as a result of the corresponding pick)?
- Is there a method you recommend to attempt to reduce the variables into something I can visualize, or otherwise analyze?